# How can i change the innerHTML content when clicking on an image?

Tags: html, image, onclick, innerhtml

I'm quite new in coding, trying to educate myself because i'm interested. So, sorry if it's going to be a bit dumb question or not so specific or not really correct...

On my "practicing site" i'm having some navigation links, which are referring to different innerHTML contents (like different pages). I used the 'onClick' event to make them show up, for example like this:

```
<div class="nav" onClick="changeNavigation('a')">menu</div>
```

It works with texts perfectly, but my problem is that i don't know how to make the same with an image. So when i click on the image, i want to be redirected to that innerHTML page, like i did it with the text based button. I tried to do it like these two ways, but none of them worked.

```
<img src="picture.png" onClick="changeNavigation('a')" />

<div onClick="changeNavigation('a')"><img src="picture.png"></div>
```

Is it possible to make this with an image and the 'onClick' event? Or how else can i make this work?

By the way this is my script to make innerHTML show up:

```
<script>
    function changeNavigation(id) {
        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
    }
</script>
```

I also tried to add my image an id that says 'main' like in the script this way, but with no result.

```
<img id="main" onClick="changeNavigation('f')" src="picture.png" />
```

Can you help me please? I would appreciate any answer, because i already searched about this and i didn't find anything that could've helped solve my problem and i'm really stuck right now.

(Sorry if my english isn't the best, it's not my native language.)

Comment: What do you mean by `innerHTML` page?  If you're just trying to jump to a section of the page on click you can use IDs and regular anchor tags.

Comment: Also, `onClick` should be all lowercase `onclick`

Comment: I mean, there are contents on (in) the site, which only showing up when i click on the menu links like i set them up the way is showed in the example. But i can't do the same whit an image. By the way making the 'onclick' lowercase didn't solved the problem and as you see i used like this: 'onClick' with the text and it worked. Or it must be used by an image with all lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my answer to what you want. You need to the divs id you want to display as a parameter to the function you use for onclick. A sample is below.

```js
var divs = ["Menu1", "Menu2", "Menu3", "Menu4"];
    var visibleDivId = null;
    function toggleVisibility(divId) {
      if(visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;
      } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
      }
      hideNonVisibleDivs();
    }
    function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
      var i, divId, div;
      for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);
        if(visibleDivId === divId) {
          div.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          div.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.main_div{text-align:center; background: #00C492; padding:20px; width: 400px;}
.inner_div{background: #fff; margin-top:20px; height: 100px;}
.buttons a{font-size: 16px;}
.buttons a:hover{cursor:pointer; font-size: 16px;}
img {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
<div class="buttons">
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/J/g/2/D/p/I/one-hi.png" width="50px"  onclick="toggleVisibility('Menu1');">  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/E/x/J/x/m/z/blue-number-two-hi.png" width="50px" onclick="toggleVisibility('Menu2');"> 
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/L/H/T/b/g/N/three-md.png" width="50px" onclick="toggleVisibility('Menu3');"> 
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/v/G/G/A/D/s/four-md.png" width="50px" onclick="toggleVisibility('Menu4');"> 
</div>
<div class="inner_div">
<div id="Menu1">I'm container one</div>
<div id="Menu2" style="display: none;">I'm container two</div>
<div id="Menu3" style="display: none;">I'm container three</div>
<div id="Menu4" style="display: none;">I'm container four</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, i don't want to "jump" like this way. When i'm clicking on one of my links, then each of them showing up different contents, like different pages, and while the one is showing up, the others doesn't. Maybe this helps you get what i mean:

<div id="a" style="display:none;"><div id="main">content</div>

I have a part like this for each "page".

Comment: It's something like i already created, and works for me like this with text. But i want to do the same with an image. So, if for example i'm clicking on an image, one of the container with it's content shows up. That's what i want to do.

Comment: If you want to simply click on an image and show a container, use the sample above but replace the link tags with the images.As long as you use the onclick function and pass it the id.

Comment: Oh, that's what i wanted, thank you so much! My method was different, but now i'm trying to redo the whole thing as you showed me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep all of the sections as children of `#main`, and selectively show them when the section button in clicked.  E.g.,

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <button type="button" data-index=0>Show one</button>
    <button type="button" data-index=1>Show two</button>
    <button type="button" data-index=2>Show three</button>
</nav>
<main id="main">
  <section>One</section>
  <section class="hidden">Two</section>
  <section class="hidden">Three</section>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
const contentBlocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section'));

function hideSections (arr) {
  arr.forEach(a => {
    a.classList.add('hidden');
  });
}

function showSection (index, sections) {
  // Just a basic check, not exhaustive by any stretch
  if (index !== undefined && sections !== undefined) {
    hideSections(sections);
    sections[index].classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const contentBlocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section'));
    const index = button.getAttribute('data-index');
    showSection(index, contentBlocks);
  });
});
```

Obviously you'll have to adjust your selectors for your use case, but [Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/monners/pen/ddYLKR)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GitHub Gist pointing to some examples I created on JSFiddle based off of your specific use case (Stack Overflow doesn't let me post links to JSFiddle directly without including code here, but it's easier to follow along/experiment entirely in JSFiddle):

https://gist.github.com/andresn/f100386f06ee28e35bd83c62d9219890

**More advanced stuff:**

Ideally, you'd use what's called event delegation instead of adding an onclick to every anchor (DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself is good to always keep in mind while programming and so is KISS = Keep It Simple Silly). Here is a resource explaining event delegation:
https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

You can even take this further by preloading all your images so they load behind the scenes when the user first loads the page:
https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Comment: It's very useful, thank you, but this is not what i exactly wanted to do. As i see, i want to make the reverse of this, what you linked. Like when i'm clicking on an image, i want some text to show up.

Comment: So the beauty of DHTML, is that the JavaScript can be agnostic to what element is being clicked on. So for instance, <a onclick=... ></a>, is the same as <img onclick=... />. This can even apply to once you get into event delegation: you can check for the classes the element has, so if el.className === 'nav-button': then delegate, i.e. call, the appropriate function to handle the event. I'll leave you with these hints in the spirit of "teach a man to fish" and let me know if you have any more questions!